# Convert an array in to an modified object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```
let a = ["CBSE/X-White","HOS/A/A1","FoodHOS/S1",
          "CBSE/X-Green","HOS/A/A2","FoodHOS/S1",
              "CBSE/IX-White","HOS/B/B1","FoodHOS/S1","TRP/T1"]
```

I am trying to convert above value of "a" to below OBJECT we can observe that it was Unique values also.

> The  output Should be like below After Converting

```
 {
    "CBSE":[
    "X-WHITE",
    "X-Green",
    "IX-White"
    ],
    "HOS":{
     "A":[
       "A1",
       "A2"
       ],
     "B":[
      "B1"
     ]
    },
   "FoodHOS":[
     "S1",
     "S2"
    ],
  "TRP":[
    "T1"
    ]
 }
```

**What I have tried:**

I am Converted the "a" in to the Below Form with this CODE

```
 const munge = a =>
                    a.reduce((res, e) => {
                        e = e.split("/");
                        let a = {};
                        let previousKey = e.shift();
                        res[previousKey] = a;
                        let root = res;
                        while (e.length) {
                            const newKey = e.shift();

                            if(e.length == 0){
                                let b = [];
                                b.push(newKey);
                                root[previousKey] = b;
                            }
                            else
                                a[newKey] = {};

                            if (e.length) {
                                root = a;
                                a= a[newKey];
                            } 
                            previousKey = newKey;
                        }

                        return res;
                    }, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(munge(a)));
```

---

```
{
   "CBSE":[
      "IX-White"
   ],
   "HOS":{
      "B":[
         "B1"
      ]
   },
   "FoodHOS":[
      "S1"
   ],
   "TRP":[
      "T1"
   ]
}
```

Acctually i am trying to make an Object which is supported to angular Tree Component 
With my DataStructure i want to comvert in to angular's Tree Comp data input,

https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jamlvojaqjeg?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the angular's material tree component, this below code will work.
>   What I have done is modified your code and added a check for the existing object.

```
let a = ["CBSE/sdfsf/X-White", "HOS/A/AA/A1", "FoodHOS/S1", "CBSE/X-Green", "HOS/A/A2",
    "FoodHOS/S1", "CBSE/IX-White", "HOS/A/B1", "FoodHOS/S1", "TRP/T1"]

// const isEmpty = (obj) => {
// return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
// }


const munge = a =>
    a.reduce((res, e) => {
        e = e.split("/");
        let a = {};
        let previousKey = e.shift();
        if (res[previousKey]) {
            a = res[previousKey];
        } else {
            res[previousKey] = a;
        }
        let root = res;
        while (e.length) {
            const newKey = e.shift();

            if (e.length == 0) {
                let b = [];
                if (root[previousKey] instanceof Array) {
                    b = root[previousKey];
                } else if (Object.keys(root[previousKey]).length) {
                    b = root[previousKey];
                }
                if (b instanceof Array) {
                    if (!b.includes(newKey))
                        b.push(newKey);
                    root[previousKey] = b;
                } else {
                    root[previousKey][newKey] = null;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (!a[newKey]) {
                    a[newKey] = {};
                }
            }

            if (e.length) {
                root = a;
                a = a[newKey];
            }
            previousKey = newKey;
        }

        return res;
    }, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(munge(a)));
```

Comment:   Thanks a lot This Code Worked for me as I Expected 

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and take it as path to the array for the value.

```js
var array = ["CBSE/X-White","HOS/A/A1","FoodHOS/S1", "CBSE/X-Green","HOS/A/A2","FoodHOS/S1", "CBSE/IX-White","HOS/B/B1","FoodHOS/S1","TRP/T1"],
    result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        var p = s.split('/'),
            v = p.pop();

        p
            .reduce((o, k, i, a) => o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === a.length ? [] : {}), r)
            .push(v);

        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please explain this statement `return o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === a.length ? [] : {})`

Comment: it checks if `o[k]` exists and if not it takes either an array (if it is the last item) or an object as default value for assignment.